# 0x80131515 thrown when initiating camera

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I get the above error when trying to set a PhotoCamera as source for a VideoBrush with the code:

```
camera = new PhotoCamera();
var videoBrush = new VideoBrush();
videoBrush.SetSource(camera);
AR.Background = videoBrush;
```

I get the following stack trace:

```
0x80131515
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.VideoBrush_SetExternalVideoSource(VideoBrush vb, IntPtr& videoSessionHandle)
at System.Windows.Media.VideoBrush.SetUpExternalVideoSession()
at Microsoft.Devices.CameraVideoBrushExtensions.SetSource(VideoBrush brush, Camera camera)
at MyClass.MyFunction()
at System.Windows.Controls.Frame.FireEventHandler[T](EventHandler`1 handler, Object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs args)
at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationPage.UIOrientationChange(ShellPageOrientation orientation)
```

The exception is thrown whether or not I am having the debugger attached.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right, I now have solved this. I think the solution could be appreciated by others so here it is;

It seems it is not possible to assign a PhotoCamera as a source to a programmatically created VideoBrush, so I edited my xaml to contain a

```
<Rectangle>
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <VideoBrush x:Name="VB" />
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

This was followed up by a simpler code

```
VB.SetSource(new PhotoCamera());
```

Furthermore this code is contained in a OnOrientationChanged event, which appearently fires multiple times, so contained in a

```
if (!processing)
{
    processing = true;

    VB.SetSource(new PhotoCamera());

    var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += (object, sender) => {
        Thread.Sleep(250);
        processing = false;
    }
}
```

the code runs smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `FrontFacing` attribute in `new PhotoCamera(CameraType.FrontFacing)` leads to the error at `SetSource()` for me. Using `CameraType.Primary` instead works fine with the programatically created `VideoBrush`. Could this have been the case for you?

Comment: I used CameraType.Primary. I think my be able to use a programmatically created VideoBrush also. The magic seems to be in the     Thread.Sleep part. And the background worker seems quite important in order not to block the UI thead.